# Transforming adress into number

Tags: contract-design

i try to transform adresses into numbers to give them strictly different values and class them with order. My operation looks not very interesting and very long.
Any idea there ?

Comment: You want to use addresses to create strictly unique invoice numbers?

Comment: Yes. Actually it is for receiving numbers.

Comment: Do you want the sender to pass in a number and check that only unique numbers are allowed. Do you want the contract to count by 1s, or something else? You can convert an address to a number, and all the different addresses will make unique numbers, but if the same customer returns, the same address will create the same number. See why I'm not sure what you want?

Comment: Yes . Thanks for the precision.   I want convert adresses using the contract into numbers. One number for one adresse. All the numbers must be followings: 1, 2, 3. ......    it is for an operation.   For another operation one adress could have another number.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want dynamic arrays. They would start counting at row 0 ... 1,2,3.

```
pragma solidity 0.4.24;

contract AddrToNumber {

    address[] public addressList; // a stateful dynamic array of addresses you can inspect with addressList(uint row)

    function pushAddess(address addToList) public {
        addressList.push(addToList); 
    }

    function getAddressCount() public view returns(uint count) {
        return addressList.length;
    }

    function convertAddrToUniqueUint(address addressToConvert) public pure returns(uint uniqueToAddress) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(addressToConvert)));
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.